# Is there simplicity to keep slider rotational by click through Jquery

Tags: jquery

I created slider having 3 slides as position absolute and clip property used. when I click on 1st slide it clips (hide right to left) and 2nd slide comes in view and same as on 2nd slide. But when I click on 3rd slide it clips from right to left but same time 1st slide unclips left to right and so on...

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slides">
        <div class="slide">1</div>
        <div class="slide">2</div>
        <div class="slide">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 80px 40px; 
    text-align: center;
    background: #333;
    clip: rect(0 1060px 660px 0);
    -webkit-transition: linear 1s;
    transition: linear 1s;
}
.slide-clip {
    clip: rect(0 0 660px 0);
}
```

Jquery script

```
$('.slide:first').click(function() {
    $(this).delay(1000).addClass('slide-clip').animate({'z-index':1});
    $('.slide:nth-child(2)').removeClass('slide-clip').animate({'z-index':3});
});

$('.slide:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
    $(this).delay(1000).addClass('slide-clip').animate({'z-index':1});
    $('.slide:last').removeClass('slide-clip').animate({'z-index':3});
});

$('.slide:last').click(function() {
    $(this).delay(1000).addClass('slide-clip').animate({'z-index':1});
    $('.slide:first').removeClass('slide-clip').animate({'z-index':3});
});
```

I expect on every click on each slide, it clip from right to left and goes to backword before that next slide unclip so it comes in viewport when prev slide clipping.

Comment: Can we please see your HTML? :)

Comment: Yea, please check, I updated.